# How does maxOccurs relate to multiple language (xml:lang) versions of the same element?

Tags: xml, xsd

Does **maxOccurs** limit the number of language versions?

What I mean is - does

```
<xs:element ref="attachments" minOccurs="0" **maxOccurs="1"**/>
```

(in XML schema), forbid:

```
<attachments>
   <audio>
      <sound url="http://bla.com/eng.mp3" xml:lang="eng"/>
      <sound url="http://bla.com/ger.mp3" xml:lang="ger"/>
   </audio>
[...]
```

And by the way, there's also "video" and "documents" sections (apart from "audio"), so I'm not sure how this schema (a real life example, not made up!) is actually supposed to work?

Just one attachment of each type? But multiple language versions OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there will be at most one `<attachments>` element (could be less because of the `minOccurs="0"`) at that particular point in the document. It does not constrain the content of the element; that would be done *inside* the definition of that element (or in its type).

Comment: So no, it doesn't forbid that fragment as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magic amount xml:lang as far as XSD is concerned; the same rules apply as if the attribute were called foobar.

Note that the maxOccurs you are showing us constrains the number of "attachments" elements within its parent element. It has no bearing on what appears inside an "attachments" element or inside an "audio" element.